# How to create line with 6th order spline?

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, matlab, interpolation, spline

I am dealing with spline interpolation and what I do is basically interpolating $6$th order ($7$ control points) spline through some discrete points. Curve-based part of my algorithm is done, however, in some points, I need to interpolate $6$th order spline which must be result in line.

Is there any mathematical method to do that ?

I thought to put $3$ control points each at start and end points and $1$ control point at the middle point of these start and end points. It seems it's working but how can I be sure that it's a line ? Or is there any other method to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. 
For future reference, you may take a look at 
[this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
to see how to format math on this site.

Comment: You need to clarify the question.
What king of the spline interpolation do you have in mind?
Is it specific kind used in `matlab`?
Does it consist of cubic Bezier segments?
Asking "how can I be sure that it's a line", 
do you mean a straight line?
Also, a picture would be very helpful
as well as a definition of the spline interpolation method used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bézier curve with six control points
[is defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Explicit_definition)

\begin{align}
\mathbf{B_6}(t)
&=
\sum _{i=0}^{6}
{6 \choose i}(1-t)^{6-i}t^{i}\,P_i
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

where $P_i$, $i=0,\dots,6$ are the control points of the spline.

Because of the properties of the convex hull of
the Bezier control points,
to get a visual appearance of the straight line
between the points $A,B$,
one can just set
$P_0=A$, $P_6=B$, and place the other five control
points somewhere on the segment $AB$,
so your choice of
$P_0,P_1,P_2=A$,
$P_4,P_5,P_6=B$,
$P_3=\tfrac12\,(A+B)$ will do for that purpose.
However, to get also the linear expression in \eqref{1},
we need to
expand \eqref{1}, in order to get
a representation as
a polynomial of degree $6$
in the standard form
\begin{align}
a_6t^6+a_5t^5+a_4t^4+a_3t^3+a_2t^2+a_1t+a_0
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

where
\begin{align}
a_0&=P_0
,\\
a_1&= 6\,(P_1-P_0)
,\\
a_2&=15\,(P_0-2\,P_1+P_2)   
,\\
a_3&=20\,(-P_0+3\,P_1-3\,P_2+P_3)
,\\
a_4&=15\,(P_0- 4 P_1 + 6 P_2 - 4 P_3+ P_4)
,\\
a_5&= 6\,(-P_0+5\,P_1-10\,P_2+10\,P_3-5\,P_4+P_5)
,\\
a_6&=P_0-6\,P_1+15\,P_2-20\,P_3+15\,P_4-6\,P_5+P_6
.
\end{align}

To get a set of control points $P_i$
such that expression \eqref{2} becomes linear in parameter $t$,
we need to make all coefficients $a_2,\dots,a_6$ zero.
The solution then is just

\begin{align}
P_i&=\tfrac16\,(A\cdot(6-i)+B\cdot i)
,\quad i=0,\dots,6
,
\end{align}

that is, all control points are
evenly distributed along the segment $AB$.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of putting three control points at each end and one in the middle will work. By a well-known property, the Bézier curve is contained in the convex hull of the control points. So, actually, you can place the control points any way you like along a line, and the Bézier curve will then be contained within that line.

In the answer by @g.kov, the idea is to distribute the control points evenly along the line segment. This is a good choice because it gives you a Bézier curve whose first derivative vector has constant magnitude.

You can get this evenly-spaced solution just by taking a Bézier curve of degree 1, and using standard degree-elevation formulas to raise its degree to 6.