# Convert cubic spline to Bézier curve and get control points

Tags: polynomials, curves, spline, bezier-curve

There is a cubic spline represented by the standard equation:
$$
    f(x) = a + b  (x - x_0) + c  (x - x_0)^2 + d  (x - x_0)^3
$$
and 2 endpoints:

- $P_0~ [x, y]$ - starting point
- $P_1~ [x, y]$ - end point

Is it possible to convert it to a cubic Bézier curve
and get all control points (`CV0` and `CV1`).

What I was thinking of is to
build a system of 2 parametric equations of the Bezier curve and 2 points
$$
    P_i(t) = (1 - t_i)^3 \cdot P_0 + 3t(1 - t_i)^2 \cdot \text{CV}_0 + 3t^2(1 - t_i) \cdot \text{CV}_1 + t_i^3 \cdot  P_1
$$
I can calculate `Pi[x, y]` that belongs to a cubic spline. But how to get the `t_i` value for the current point? Or there is different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align} 
f(x) &= a + b  (x - x_0) + c  (x - x_0)^2 + d  (x - x_0)^3
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Note that \eqref{1} defines $y$ as a function of $x$.
Combined with two values of $x$, $x_0$ and $x_3$,
we have all we need to
make a conversion to equivalent 2D cubic Bezier segment,
defined by its four control points

\begin{align} 
P_0(x_0,y_0),\,&P_1(x_1,y_1),\,P_2(x_2,y_2),\,P_3(x_3,y_3)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}
The end points are

\begin{align} 
P_0&=(x_0,y_0)=(x_0,f(x_0))=(x_0,a)
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
P_3&=(x_3,y_3)=(x_3,f(x_3))
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

2D cubic Bezier segment is defined as usual,

\begin{align} 
B_3(t)&=(x(t),y(t))
\tag{5}\label{5}
,\\
x(t)&=x_0\,(1-t)^3+3\,x_1\,(1-t)^2\,t+3\,x_2\,(1-t)\,t^2+x_3\,t^3
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
y(t)&=y_0\,(1-t)^3+3\,y_1\,(1-t)^2\,t+3\,y_2\,(1-t)\,t^2+y_3\,t^3
,\quad t\in[0,1]
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}

We know that $x$ is linear in $t$, so
we must have
\begin{align}
x_0\,(1-t)+x_3\,t
&=x_0\,(1-t)^3+3\,x_1\,(1-t)^2\,t+3\,x_2\,(1-t)\,t^2+x_3\,t^3
\tag{8}\label{8}
,\\
(x_3-x_0)t+x_0
&=(3x_1-x_0-3x_2+x_3)t^3+(3x_0+3x_2-6x_1)t^2+3(x_1-x_0)t+x_0
\quad \forall t\in[0,1]
\tag{9}\label{9}
,
\end{align}

hence we have $x_1,x_2$ evenly distributed between the endpoints $x_0$ and $x_3$:

\begin{align}
x_1 &= \tfrac13 (2x_0+x_3)=x(t)\Big|_{t=1/3}
\tag{10}\label{10}
,\\
x_2 &= \tfrac13 (x_0+2x_3)=x(t)\Big|_{t=2/3}
\tag{11}\label{11}
.
\end{align}

Corresponding $y$ points on the curve \eqref{1}
are

\begin{align}
y(\tfrac13)&=f(x_1)
\tag{12}\label{12}
,\\
y(\tfrac23)&=f(x_2)
\tag{13}\label{13}
.
\end{align}

The last pair of equations is a linear system
with two unknowns, $y_1$ and $y_2$
which can be trivially solved as

\begin{align} 
y_1
&=
\tfrac13\,b\,(x_3-x_0)+a
\tag{14}\label{14}
,\\
y_2
&=
\tfrac13(x_3-x_0)(c(x_3-x_0)+2b)+a
\tag{15}\label{15}
.
\end{align}

Example

[image]

\begin{align} 
a   &=  7
,\quad
b   =  2
,\quad
c   =  2
,\quad
d   = -1
\tag{16}\label{16}
,\\
x_0 &= -1
,\quad
x_3 =  3
\tag{17}\label{17}
,\\
y_0&=a=7
,\quad
y_3=f(3)=-17
\tag{18}\label{18}
,\\
x_1 &= \tfrac13(2x_0+x_3)=\tfrac13
\tag{19}\label{19}
,\\
x_2 &= \tfrac13(x_0+2x_3)=\tfrac53
\tag{20}\label{20}
,\\
y_1
&=
\tfrac13\,b\,(x_3-x_0)+a
=\tfrac{29}3
\tag{21}\label{21}
,\\
y_2
&=
\tfrac13(x_3-x_0)(c(x_3-x_0)+2b)+a
=23
\tag{22}\label{22}
.
\end{align}

Comment: I am extremely grateful for your time on such a detailed answer. I have seen the use of `1/3 (2/3)` in other sources, but did not understand where it comes from and why. Thank you @g.kov !

Comment: @newWeb: My pleasure, and welcome to Math.SE.
If you've found the answer useful, 
you can [mark it as "accepted"](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @newWeb: Also, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3761077/122782)
you could find some more info on the representation
of linear segments in the form of higher order Bezier curves.

Comment: Should't `y1 = a = 7` be `y0 = a = 7`?

Comment: @ SSteve:Yes, thanks, typo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume a curve defined on $t\in[0,1]$

$$x(t)=a+bt+ct^2+dt^3$$

with the boundary conditions

$$x_0=a,\\x'_0=b,\\x_1=a+b+c+d,\\x'_1=b+2c+3d.$$

From this we draw

$$a=x_0,\\b=x'_0,\\c=3(x_1-x_0)-x'_1-2x'_0,\\d=-2(x_1-x_0)+x'_1+x'_0.$$

Now the Bezier polynomial is

$$w_0(1-t)^3+3w_1(1-t)^2t+3w_2(1-t)t^2+w_3t^3=
\\w_0+3(w_1-w_0)t+3(w_2-2w_1+w_0)t^2+(w_3-3w_2+3w_1-w_0)t^3.$$

We can identify to the standard form and solve the triangular system. This gives

$$w_0=a=x_0,\\w_1=\frac b3+a=\frac{x'_0}3+x_0,\\w_2=\frac c3+\frac{2b}3+a=-\frac{x'_1}3+x_1,\\w_3=d+c+b+a=x_1.$$